# Date Format SQL Query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I wrote the following query in a Google Sheet:

`=QUERY(Prospects!$B$2:$DV; select D, L, B, AC, AH where Y = 'Aceptado' AND B > 42781 AND D IS NOT NULL  order by B  Asc   label D 'Cliente'; 1)`

42781 refers to a date (15/02/2017)

The query is well constructed but it doesn't return any values (no results).

If the date filter is removed the query returns lots of results so the issue is related to the date format.

`=QUERY(Prospects!$B$2:$DV; select D, L, B, AC, AH where Y = 'Aceptado' AND D IS NOT NULL  order by B  Asc   label D 'Cliente'; 1)`

There are lots of results with B > 42781 (or B > "15/02/2017"). How should I enter the date value?

Thanks

Comment: Your link helped me a lot. thnx! 

On the other hand I couldn't fix it completely due to the following issue:

I'm adding 2 date filters and the second date filter is based on the first ($F$5 + 30). This 'date YYYY-MM-DD' format doesn't work on the second and I don't know why ///

`where B >= date '"&$F$5&"' AND "& B <= date ' "&$F$5 + 30&" ' "`

Comment: You should use TEXT() https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-spreadsheet%5D+query+date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using   `AND B > date '2017-02-15'`
It was the [first link](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/) I got searching on Google...